# Difference in time format in json in mockmvc tests between SpringBootTest and WebMvcTest

Tags: json, spring-boot, mockmvc, offsetdatetime

I'm testing a REST controller in Spring Boot with mockMvc. One of the request parameters has a property of type OffsetTime.
When I use the following annotations:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebMvcTest(MyController.class)
```

the following condition in mockMvc is true:
.andExpect(jsonPath("$.createdTime", is("2018-05-05T10:11:12.123+02:00")))

However, when I swith the annotations (because I have to use some extra converters) to:

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
```

I get the following error in the test:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: JSON path "$.createdTime"
Expected: is "2018-05-05T10:11:12.123+02:00"
     but: was <1525507872.123000000>
```

In fact I don't want the timestamp in the SpringBootTest either, I want the latter to serialize the date in the "offset" format.

How can I achieve it? adding

```
spring:
  jackson:
    serialization:
      write-dates-as-timestamps: false
```

to application.yml did not change anything for the spring boot test.

Comment: This helped me with the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69012206/incorrect-serialization-of-zoneddatetime-in-junit-tests-date-returns-as-double